# Approximation factor shorthand clarification

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, approximation

I'm starting to dabble in the world of approximation algorithms and had a question about the convention many papers will use when talking about the *approximation factor*. I know that an approximation factor will give the factor within which the algorithm will perform with respect to the optimal solution. This is pretty easy to grasp for things like a 2-factor approximation. I've also seen other literature and lecture notes refer to $1-1/\epsilon$ when giving the probability and/or percentage of the optimal that will be returned (or, put another way, how "much" of the optimal an approximation algorithm will, well, approximate).

But I've seen some papers (like [Linear-Time Approximation for Maximum Weight Matching](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2578041.2529989)
) refer to a $1-\epsilon$ approximation ratio. For example:

> we give an algorithm that computes a (1 − ε)-approximate maximum weight matching

So my question is: are they referring to the $1-1/\epsilon$ ratio that I've been seeing elsewhere? Apologies if this is a simplistic question, I'm just getting starting in learning about these very-cool algorithms and am trying to get my head around which papers are presenting things that are extraordinary vs. not as competitive compared to the optimal solution. Thank you!

Comment: The expression $1-1/\epsilon$ makes little sense. However, $1-1/e$ is quite common. Here $e$ is the well-known constant.

Comment: Sometimes approximation ratios are larger than 1, sometimes smaller. Both mean the same thing. A 2-approximation is exactly the same thing as a 1/2-approximation. Which convention gets used is quite arbitrary, and in some cases different authors use different conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That article, [Linear-Time Approximation for Maximum Weight Matching](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2529989) calls "a matching $\delta$-approximate, where $\delta \in [0, 1]$, if its weight is at least a factor $\delta$ of the optimum matching."

That $\delta$-approximate maximum weight is, in fact, similar to the 2-factor approximation that is easy for you to grasp. When the optimization problem is to minimize some (positive) quantity, such as the minimum traveling distance or minimum vertex cover, then a 2-factor approximate might appear. When the optimization problem is to maximize some (positive) quantity, such as the case here, then a $(1-\frac15)$-factor approximate might be expected.

You may want to take a look at the [*performance guarantees of approximation algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm#Performance_guarantees) or even [*what is a bicriteria approximation algorithm?*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26028/what-is-a-bicriteria-approximation-algorithm)